# Slow first NpgsqlConnection in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: npgsql, yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

It seems that connecting to a cluster is “slow” the first time through NpgsqlConnection.
Is this normal PostgreSQL behaviour or is this related to YugabyteDB?
We are using the latest 6.0.0-preview7 nuget to use the multi host connecting string for load balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Allow extensibility in type loading and database capabilities · Issue #1486 · npgsql/npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1486), extra calls are made to system tables to map types when the first connection is created. In order to avoid the initial call, you can set `connStringBuilder.ServerCompatibilityMode = ServerCompatibilityMode.NoTypeLoading;` on the connection string. When setting this property the first call is not made and the connection will be faster.